# How to install the php interpreter in wamp on windows 7

Tags: php, wamp

I have just spent over an hour trying to find what the php interpreter filename is and where it is located. Please help. I am running Windows 7 and WAMP.

Comment: Do you mean the cli or command line interpretor?

Comment: In `cmd.exe` type `where php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the php files in wamp they should be in this directory:

The version name might be different from the one I am using.

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\

Comment: Thank you. If someone wants to vote me down go ahead but remember you were once learning and needed help. To start with I sometimes don't even really know what I want, I just know what I am trying to do.

Comment: You asked a legitimate question and you stated that you have you looked for over an hour so I wouldn't worry about it.  That is why people should post questions.  You needed help and tried to solve it on your own.